# Jade parse error

Tags: node.js, pug

Update:

I just found that I installed the latest code for node. I just re-installed last stable version and it seems to work fine for me.

JUST FYI -  The node version I was using -

Mac-mini:helloworld nimahajan$ npm -v
1.3.11
Mac-mini:helloworld nimahajan$ node -v
v0.11.8-pre

=========================================================

I am trying to create a simple hello world example.

After npm install and node app.js, I always get below error and can't seem to 
get around this ..

jade@0.35.0 
express@3.4.0

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'parse'
    at detect (/Users/nimahajan/Desktop/Hapus/node/MEAN/MySite/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/index.js:33:22)
    at addWith (/Users/nimahajan/Desktop/Hapus/node/MEAN/MySite/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/index.js:8:28)
    at parse (/Users/nimahajan/Desktop/Hapus/node/MEAN/MySite/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:105:11)
    at Object.exports.compile (/Users/nimahajan/Desktop/Hapus/node/MEAN/MySite/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:142:9)
    at Object.exports.render (/Users/nimahajan/Desktop/Hapus/node/MEAN/MySite/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:196:15)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/Users/nimahajan/Desktop/Hapus/node/MEAN/MySite/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:233:18)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/nimahajan/Desktop/Hapus/node/MEAN/MySite/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:218:21)
    at View.render (/Users/nimahajan/Desktop/Hapus/node/MEAN/MySite/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render (/Users/nimahajan/Desktop/Hapus/node/MEAN/MySite/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:506:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/nimahajan/Desktop/Hapus/node/MEAN/MySite/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:798:7)
```

App.js

```
/*
 * Module dependencies
 */
var express = require('express')
  , stylus = require('stylus')
  , nib = require('nib');

var app = express()
function compile(str, path) {
  return stylus(str)
    .set('filename', path)
    .use(nib())
}
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.use(express.logger('dev'))
app.use(stylus.middleware(
  { src: __dirname + '/public'
  , compile: compile
  }
))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index',
  { title : 'Home' }
  )
});

app.listen(3000);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "MySite",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "jade": "*",
    "stylus": "*",
    "nib": "*"
  }
}
```

I am following below example basically,
http://clock.co.uk/tech-blogs/a-simple-website-in-nodejs-with-express-jade-and-stylus

Comment: Yeah, I just ran through the tutorial you referenced and it works fine. I'm guessing its a problem with your Jade code, either the layout or index file. The only thing I did that the tutorial missed was to create a public/stylesheets directory and add a style.css file to it.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error just trying to use the normal npm scaffolding procedure.
Could it be a bug
With following package configuration:

```
{
  "name"         : "todo",
  "version"      : "0.0.1",
  "private"      : true,
  "dependencies" : {
    "jade"     : "*",
    "connect"  : "*",
    "express"  : "*",
    "ejs"      : "*",
    "mongoose" : "*"
  }
}
```