# NodeJS Express: #<Object> has no method 'parse'

Tags: node.js, express

I have a problem with NodeJS.express when I create a new package by using:

```
express test_web
```

It created successfully, but when I open `localhost:3000` main page, it cannot access to `parse` method!

this is a full page what it come:

```
Express
500 TypeError: /Users/user/Documents/p/hello_test/views/index.jade:5 3| block content 4| h1= title > 5| p Welcome to #{title} Object #<Object> has no method 'parse'
at detect (/Users/user/Documents/p/hello_test/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/index.js:33:22)
at addWith (/Users/user/Documents/p/hello_test/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/index.js:8:28)
at parse (/Users/user/Documents/p/hello_test/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:105:11)
at Object.exports.compile (/Users/user/Documents/p/hello_test/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:142:9)
at Object.exports.render (/Users/user/Documents/p/hello_test/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:196:15)
at Object.exports.renderFile (/Users/user/Documents/p/hello_test/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:233:18)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/user/Documents/p/hello_test/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:218:21)
at View.render (/Users/user/Documents/p/hello_test/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8)
at Function.app.render (/Users/user/Documents/p/hello_test/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:506:10)
at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/user/Documents/p/hello_test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:803:7)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you install jade with `npm install -d`

Comment: Post the code you're using to render the page.

Comment: this user solved the same problem by using a different version of node. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084726/jade-parse-error

Comment: @hexacyanide its a default code, I didn't add anything, when I created an application.

Comment: @Plato I have same versions, how did he solved it? I'm re-install `jade` again, but not solved...

Comment: the structure of my app folder is: 3 folders only,
- Public 
- Views
- routes
- app.js
- package json

Comment: try using a different version of node. if you have [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) it's as simple as `nvm install 0.9; nvm use 0.9`

Comment: It solved after using nvm. Thanks plato :)

Comment: great! i wonder what was broken...

Answer (score 1):

Install this version  http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.21/node-v0.10.21.tar.gz and the error goes away.